# Compare two dataframes based on two columns and printing the matching values and grouping the matching values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes like this,

```
>>df1
  name key1 key2   A   B
0  a1  1    K0   A0   B0
1  a2  2    K1   A1   B1
2  a3  3    K0   A2   B2
3  a3  4    K1   A3   B3

>>df2
  key1 key2 
0   1   K0  
1   2   K0  
2   3   0K  
3   4   1K
```

I need to compare key1,key2 of df1 with df2 and I have to print the matching rows. While comparing  I have to check df1['key1','key2'] == df2['key1','key2'] or df1['key1','key2'] == df2['key1',reverse('key2')]

Expected Output:

```
>>df3
      name key1 key2   A   B  
       a1  1    K0   A0   B0  
       a3  3    K0   A2   B2  
       a3  4    K1   A3   B3  
>>df4
      name key1 key2   A      B      
       a1  1    K0     A0     B0     
       a3  3,4  K0,K1  A2,A3  B2,B3
```

Comment: kindly post your expected output. you can also include what you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try with [`MultiIndex.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.isin.html)

```
i1 = df1.set_index(['key1', 'key2']).index
i2 = df2.set_index(['key1', 'key2']).index
i3 = df2.set_index(['key1', df2['key2'].str[::-1]]).index

df3 = df1[i1.isin(i2.union(i3))]
df4 = df3.astype(str).groupby('name', as_index=False).agg(','.join)
```

---

```
print(df3)
  name  key1 key2   A   B
0   a1     1   K0  A0  B0
2   a3     3   K0  A2  B2
3   a3     4   K1  A3  B3

print(df4)
  name key1   key2      A      B
0   a1    1     K0     A0     B0
1   a3  3,4  K0,K1  A2,A3  B2,B3
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
x = df1.merge(df2, on=["key1", "key2"])
df2["key2"] = df2["key2"].str[::-1]
y = df1.merge(df2, on=["key1", "key2"])

df3 = pd.concat([x, y])
df4 = (
    df3.assign(key1=df3.key1.astype(str))
    .groupby("name", as_index=False)
    .agg(", ".join)
)

print(df3)
print(df4)
```

Prints:

```
  name  key1 key2   A   B
0   a1     1   K0  A0  B0
0   a3     3   K0  A2  B2
1   a3     4   K1  A3  B3

  name  key1    key2       A       B
0   a1     1      K0      A0      B0
1   a3  3, 4  K0, K1  A2, A3  B2, B3
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach:

1. Get `ord` for each character in key2 and sum them up to create a helper column.
2. Then use this column in merge. This will eliminate the need of reversing the string.

---

```
f = lambda x: sum(map(ord,x))
df4 = (df1.merge(df2,left_on=['key1',df1['key2'].map(f)],
              right_on=['key1',df2['key2'].map(f)],suffixes=('','_y'))
 .loc[:,df1.columns]
.groupby("name", as_index=False).agg(lambda x: ', '.join(x.map(str))))
```

---

```
print(df4)

 name  key1    key2       A       B
0   a1     1      K0      A0      B0
1   a3  3, 4  K0, K1  A2, A3  B2, B3
```

Note that you receive `df3` if you remove the `groupby` operation from the code above.